# Android. Action overflow. Меню настроен снизу

Tags: android, menu, android-menu, settings, action

Подскажите, как сделать вот такое меню в панели снизу?
[image]

Comment: Вы не можете добавлять в это меню элементы без изменения прошивки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правило, нижняя панель с кнопками, куда ты хочешь добавить `ActionOverflow`, принадлежит к числу системных приложений, а именно к `SystemUI.apk`. Так что приложении у тебя не получится добавить такое меню. Тем не менее, ты можешь добавить

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

и реализовать все там, по мне так оно никак не хуже.

Comment: В таком случае, как это сделали, например, в этом http://vk.cc/5dp2ak приложении?

Comment: @Viewed но там же ничего нет)

Comment: Есть! http://vk.cc/5dqsSL

Comment: @Viewed нет, это зависит от твоей прошивки и какой у тебя System.UI

Comment: @Viewed https://goo.gl/photos/UFjhEf1AZwEprPAj7

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо